# Reading a txt file in php and parsing the data to MySQL

Tags: php

im new to php and i hope you can help with an easy to get script. I have a txt file with this general format:

```
5TB-2A, L+, 1, 1695, 3255, l.jpg
5TB-2A, L-, 2, 1965, 3270, l.jpg
5TB-2A, D-, 7, 2970, 3270, l.jpg
5TB-2A, DFOK, 8, 3225, 3300, l.jpg
```

I want to read this txt file using php to retrive every data separated by "," into my MySQL table. Thanks for any help.

Comment: MySQL supports importing CSV or similar text files with the `LOAD DATA INFILE` syntax, just as a general comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$lines=file($yourTxt);

foreach($lines as $v) {
   $values = explode(',',$v);
   PDO::prepare("INSERT INTO tbl (?,?,?,?,?)");
   PDO::execute($values);
}
```

You can make a further check too see if the line just read is ok like:

```
foreach($lines as $v) {
   $values = explode(',',$v);
   if (count($values)!=6)
     continue;
}
```

Comment: Sometimes it's useful to pass FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES as second argument.

Answer (score 1):

You could use fgetcsv (http://php.net/fgetcsv) to read the file into an array in PHP and then write a query to insert it into the table one row at a time.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$results =   array();
$rows    =   file($filename, FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
if(empty($rows)){
   // no data to parse
} else{
    foreach($rows as $row){
        $values = explode(', ', $row);
        // keep only those values which have the 5 variables
        if(count($values) > 5){
            $results[] = $values;
        }
    }
}

// see if we have the correct data
print_r($results);

// ... then do your db inserts here

?>
```